# the cors error in full stack angular and laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, cors

I am developing full stack, front-end is ngx-admin(angular) and back-end is laravel.
The cors error occurs in the images I attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aVrt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ZLE.png)

how to fix it?

thank you.

I want to login using JWT.

Comment: Both servers are running on different ports you have to enable the Crose browser policy in your Laravel app. Or allow the port of your angular server into Laravel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you Khalid. can you give me detailed important code?